# Equal column width not working when use text right in CSS Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want the grid columns to be equal in width whether it will be one, two, or more columns, Also
the column gap must be the same. I found one of the examples but when using `text-right` for columns the column width seems not equal. Anyone helps me to achieve this?
[image: img]
In the following example, column gap spacing and width are not equal. I want to achieve using CSS or JS.

```css
.grid-equal-columns {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}
.grid-equal-columns > * {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-equal-columns">
  <div>Sample</div>
  <div>12122</div><div>hello text</div> 
    <div>44444</div> 
  <div>5555</div><div>6666666666666666666666666</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Remove `grid-auto-columns: 1fr;`?

Comment: add background to your div and you will notice that your columns are equal

Answer (score 0):

```
grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
```

creates 1fr columns equally distributed to the grid. regardless how long your text will be in the the cell.

You can achieve two ways.

remove `grid-auto-columns: 1fr;`

```css
.grid-equal-columns {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.grid-equal-columns > * {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-equal-columns">
  <div>Sample</div>
  <div>12122</div>
  <div>hello text</div> 
    <div>44444</div> 
  <div>5555</div>
  <div> 6666666666666666666666666</div>
</div>
```

or use `flexbox` with `justify-content: space-evenly`

```css
.grid-equal-columns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.grid-equal-columns > * {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-equal-columns">
  <div>Sample</div>
  <div>12122</div>
  <div>hello text</div> 
    <div>44444</div> 
  <div>5555</div>
  <div>6666666666666666666666666</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide fix width to your `grid-column` so, it's take fix `width` and your every `column` should be same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <style>
      .grid-equal-columns {
      display: grid;
      grid-auto-flow: column;
      grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
      }
      .grid-equal-columns > * {
      width: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: right;
      margin: 10px;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div class="grid-equal-columns">
      <div>Sample</div>
      <div>12122</div>
      <div>hello text</div>
      <div>44444</div>
      <div>5555</div>
      <div>6666666666666666666666666</div</div>
   </body>
</html>
```